# Hp primary internal battery error 601 at boot

Tags: boot, battery, hp-pavilion

I was using ubuntu 12.04 and a file transfer was going on when i saw the battery applet was showing 1 min remaining. I immediately shut down the laptop and when i plugged it after some time, from that moment onwards at the boot time this message is showing up for 15 sec -

```
HP Battery Alert
The system has detected the storage capacity of the battery stated below to be very low. For optimal performance, this battery may need to be replaced.
Primary (internal) Battery (601)
ENTER - Continue Startup
For more information, please visit: www.hp.com/go/techcenter
```

I am sure the battery is just fine since it is working just fine. I also tried removing and inserting the battery again several times. I tried fully charging the battery but the message keep showing up. How to solve the issue or atleast diable the message and boot normally. **It is happening at the boot time before the os loads.**

I also tried to do [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00821536&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en) but the in **system diagnosis** the battery test option is missing.

My laptop - **HP PAVILION DV6 6155-TX**

Comment: have you tried charging the battery all the way through with the system shut down?

Comment: You mean charging the batttery without starting laptop ? No. I will try that as soon as i discharge my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately HP has had several battery recalls over the past few years. Tech forums are filled with HP 601 error complaints. I spent about 30 min researching your issue with no success. I believe your battery will need to be replaced.

You can try unplugging the laptop - removing the battery - and holding the power button down for at least 60 sec - restart

On most laptops this resets factory configuration defaults and may clear the 601 error. It's a shot in the dark, but you never know.

Comment: if i remove the battery and unplug it how can it reset to factory. The power button won't work, coz there is no power supply. Please tell me !

Comment: i unplugged the laptop and while battery is inserted i long pressed the power button. After some seconds the display got dark and i panicked.

Comment: While holding down the power button with cable and battery removed, it allows the remaining power in the capacitors to discharge. Once all power is removed the system defaults. I have only used this trick once before in the past, but it worked. Like I said, it's a long shot given the large quantity of HP battery issues going around.

Comment: No luck at all. I think i have to live with it until i buy a new battery.

Answer (score 4):

I worked at HP: 601 & 602 are battery BIOS POST (power-on-self-test) messages advising the battery has deteriorated past 25% of its original capacity & suggesting a replacement. Its built into their bios & indeed you should have an option to test the battery in the bios, however since that's a consumer model I can't say for sure. I don't know how to rid the message off the top of my head (not on my PC now), if you figure it out definitely come back & advise. If no one provides a solution comment on this answer to remind me to see if I can find info on it

UPDATE 1-15-14:
You note you followed an HP guide to do a battery test but its missing. The diagnostics (F2) is installed on a partition called HP_TOOLS. I imagine you wiped it when you installed Ubuntu. [Their installers to get it working requires windows](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-93497-3&cc=in&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=5167397), so you're option are: dual-boot windows (if you haven't) & run it in windows OR run it on another PC & it will give you the option to install the diagnostics on a USB Flash/Thumb drive. I am still of the mindset your battery is going bad & I'd simply replace it or ignore the message. Maybe you can get more info on battery health in Ubuntu?

I found documents below that seem to indicate you cannot disable the 601 error on startup (POST). Well technically you can by getting a new battery, but you knew that

- http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01443470
- http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01443470#N33
- http://h20239.www2.hp.com/techcenter/battery/battery_ts.htm

Comment: Search for an HP firmware update and flash the BIOS. I do not recommend this, but if HP fixed the problem in the update then it solves your problem. That's the best I have to offer.

Comment: Problem with me is that i feel so much lost while find updates let it be a driver or firmware. So please if you can provide me with anything like any link etc.